# How can I select the text within an element, copy it and then paste it elsewhere on the page? Selenium webdriver python;

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[EDIT image][1]

[Link to the website][2]

[Image 1][3]

[Image 2][4]

So this is a forum that customers post questions on seeking answers. The question is made by the customer who is the first poster. What I am trying to do is locate the text of the name of the first poster, in this case being user "davidbrigden" and then copy their name. Next, after pressing reply (shown in second ss) I would like to paste the name that I copied from the first poster in the reply box, to let them know I am responding to them specifically. However, I am currently not able to figure out how to do this. Help appreciated.

My code for selecting the reply option:

```
reply_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@title="Reply"]')
reply_buttons[0].click()
```

Comment: Rather than copy-paste, it seems it would be better to grab this text, store it in a variable, then send it to the field where you reply.

Comment: As we discussed this previously, you are doing this actions while you are already logged into the site. In this case by pressing the reply button the replay commenting dialog is opened starting with the user name. https://ibb.co/Nr9sQ4H

Comment: @Prophet unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, although the reply option is selected (with the code you suggested previously) it ignores the "@Username" and just shows an empty reply box. I also initially thought that it would automatically reply with the user's name, this only seems to be the case when you manually press the reply button rather than when selenium does it for you. To overcome this I aim to copy and paste the original poster's name in the reply box once pressed.

Comment: Strange... OK, will try giving you solution shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate user's user names from the post headers with this css_selector:

```
'.PostUser .username'
```

So, you can get all the posts users names as following

```
answer_names= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.PostUser .username')
```

The first answered user name is

```
first_answer_user_name = answer_names[0].text
```

the replay comment textarea element is located by following css_selector

```
`#composer textarea`
```

So, you can send text there by:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#composer textarea').send_keys(first_answer_user_name)
```

**UPD:**
Altogether it will look as following:

```
time.sleep(5)
answer_names= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.PostUser .username')
first_answer_user_name = answer_names[0].text
reply_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@title="Reply"]')
reply_buttons[0].click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#composer textarea').send_keys(first_answer_user_name)
```

Don't forget adding waits / delays.
I added sleeps for simplification, expected conditions should be used instead

Comment: This is helpful but could you show how this would all look together as a bunch of code? I am a little confused. Also the line: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(`#composer textarea`)send_keys(first_answer_user_name) , returns with syntax errors due to the # being there, and even after adjusting the code the first user's name isn't written out. I feel there is something I am missing.

Comment: This seems to make sense, thanks. However, the line : driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#composer textarea')send_keys(first_answer_user_name) , leads to an invalid syntax and the "s" in send_keys is highlighted, I have updated my original post to show a screenshot of the code.

Comment: Sure, it's my copy-paste mistake. it should be `find_element_by_css_selector`, not `find_elements_by_css_selector`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the names of all the users on the page like this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.PostUser-badges.badges')
names = []
for element in elements:
    names.append(element.text)
```

Then if you want to reply with the "davidbrigden" name, use

```
reply_field_element.send_keys(names[0])
```

Comment: I seem to get this error: reply_field_element.send_keys(names[0])
NameError: name 'reply_field_element' is not defined

Comment: my code so far looks something like this : elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.PostUser-badges.badges')
names = []
for element in elements:
    names.append(element.text)

reply_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@title="Reply"]')
reply_buttons[0].click()

reply_field_element.send_keys(names[0])

Comment: you need to replace `reply_field_element` with whatever locates the reply field. You have to sign in to reply, so I can't see the reply field to help you with that.